# Why does '[' + array + ']' return a normal array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

So I was just writing some code and realized that adding square brackets around an array just returns a complete, normal array like below,

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3]
var addSquareBrackets = function(arr) {
    return '[' + arr + ']';
}

addSquareBrackets(arr); // <- returns [1, 2, 3]
```

and same thing happens when concatenating curly brackets around an array.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3]
var addCurlyBrackets = function(arr) {
    return '{' + arr + '}';
}

addCurlyBrackets(arr); // <- returns {1, 2, 3}
```

It seems odd to me how the first example returns [1, 2, 3], instead of [[1, 2, 3]] or the second example returns {1, 2, 3}, instead of {[1, 2, 3]}.
Can someone help me understand why this happens?

Comment: it returns a string (with a joined array) which is not an array ...

Comment: Because you're trying to concatenate an array with a string so it's doing some automatic casting.

Comment: if you will log `typeof add***Brackets(arr)`, you will get `string`, not array or object.

Comment: Oh, thank you guys. I was fooled by the looks of it. Thank you all for your comments!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `+` operator, whenever you have a string on one side, whatever expression on the other side gets coerced into a string as well.

Arrays, when coerced to strings, have `.join(',')` called on them:

```js
console.log(String([1, 2, 3]));
```

They do *not* get `[` `]` array delimiters added around the result - they just get the plain values joined together by commas.

Comment: Thank you, so after all it is a simple type coercion. Now I get it. Thank you so much for your time and answer!